# Where is the GUI button press sound file for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I am making a custom modpack, and I need to change the GUI button press sound for my modpack, but I don't know where the sound file is for clicking the GUI button.

Comment: This question may have been already answered here: [Minecraft sound(ogg) files disappeared in 1.8](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/199565/90489)

Answer (score 3):

Learning to better help yourself is a wonderful thing, it helps you the most! With most things programming, doing a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=change%20minecraft%20sounds) first is typically the best route.

Then there's the option of reading the documentation for the thing you're working on. Often they have [helpful tutorials](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Sound_directory) or manuals to help you. Once you find a good source for documentation, it's typically best to look there first.

Finally, you can ask a question on a forum specific to the thing you're working on (but remember to always search the forum for an answer before asking a new one!), or if your question is more general, on a site for more general development in the field you're working in.

Specifically for your question:

> Sound directory (after 1.7.2)
>
> The sound files in
>   version 1.7.2 (specifically 13w42a) and above are scattered and hashed
>   into different folders, which are located in:
>
> Windows: %AppData%.minecraft\assets\objects
>   Mac OS X:
>   ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/assets/objects
>  Linux:
>   ~/.minecraft/assets/objects

Answer (score 2):

Copying my answer from [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/199565/90489).

---

#### How to find a sound file

1. Open `\.minecraft\assets\indexes\<version>.json`. `<version>` can be `1.7.10`, `1.8`, `14w25b`, etc.
2. In the index file, you can find a organized list of assets and some informations(hash and size) about them. `cave9.ogg` for example,

   > "minecraft/sounds/ambient/cave/cave9.ogg": {
   >    **"hash"**: **"b463fa47816fe9a5dfe508093150e647403e4db6"**,
   >    "size": 27096
   >   }

   has a hash value of `b463fa47…`. Remember first 2 digits(in this case `b4`).
3. The actual sound file is located at `.minecraft\assets\objects\<first 2 digits>\` with a filename being a `<hash>` without any extension. For example, `cave9.ogg` is located at `.minecraft\assets\objects\b4\` with a filename `b463fa47816fe9a5dfe508093150e647403e4db6` without extension.

---

In your case the filename is `click.ogg`.